# what does the scope in the linker function represent in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs

What does the scope parameter in the link property of the directive definition object represent. Is it the scope that the directive will be used in or is it an isolated scope for every time the directive is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not define scope in your directive then it has access to your parent scope.  If you define it as

```
scope: {}
```

Then an isolate scope is created.

Should be able to see more in the docs, but that is a basic rundown.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive